# Address bar in Firefox greyed/blacked out

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have actually had this happen already once when I first installed Ubuntu 12.04 but was able to fix the issue by going into about:config and changing an entry to false. However I have now upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 running KDE desktop and have the same issue which I was unable to resolve using the fix I had used previously. I also tried another fix that was mentioned on lifehacker.com where it tells you to try and change a different config setting to = false and still had no luck, I also closed firefox completely after making each change and reopened to see the issue was still occurring and also confirmed that the values of both the strings I had modified to =false were still indeed set to false. Anyone got any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 I tried the  "about:config"  and changed the "gfx.xrender.enabled" to false by double clicking and it worked for me. Why don't try to uninstall and reinstall firefox? or maybe set it to true exit out and if the gray boxes aren't gone try re-enable false. Not sure what else to tell you man I hope that works or someone else more knowledgeable helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the gfx.xrender.enabled value to false works for me. If it doesn't work for you, I saw this thread, and others, where it was mentioned some folks got joy on this issue by installing a particular theme:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/999333